# What is the way to prove termination of a contract?

Tags: contracts, contract-cancellation

The competition clause of my consultancy agreement contains that

*The resignation means that the consultant is ineligible during 1 year after the retirement date to begin, take employment with, or directly or indirectly interested in any business wholly or partly competes with the business which the company operates at the consultant's resignation.*

What is the official way to prove that I terminated a contract on a certain date? If 1 year after the terminated I will start business in the same industry I would no get into any trouble.

Is it enough if I have sent e-mail to the CEO?

Comment: Was your email your formal resignation, and did you get your tax documentation from the business?

Comment: Yes it was kind of a formal "resignation", even dow it is not a resignation but the termination of my contract, because I am a contractor. And so I get no taxation document because I am responsible for my own taxation.

Comment: Random question, what country are you in? I only ask, because I have heard about some countries not enforcing those type of clauses.

Comment: The EU has very strong laws aimed at protecting livelihood which often make these types of clauses void, even if they are often written into contracts. Be sure to check the countries laws before assuming that the clause is valid.

Answer (score 1):

The answer probably depends on the country, as @Canadian Luke points out.

I have worked in four countries, and companies usually provide a formal letter, stating the formal end date of the contract.

Such a letter is easy to write. Your company should provide it to you, even retrospectively. If they do not have a template yet, there are many samples across the web to pass them.

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to contact the company and get them to provide you a headed letter that proves when you let contract was terminated as this provides everything you should need in one letter.